# Getting image from Gallary and set it in recyclerview

Tags: android, kotlin, android-recyclerview, handler

I have a recycler view and have to set image in recycler view. I already have given permission and got the image in my form but from the form I  have to send it in my recyclerview card.

I tried bitmap process but was not successful.

**MainActivity:**

```java
    package com.example.itemgetset
    
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
    import android.app.Activity
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.Handler
    import android.os.Message
    import android.view.Menu
    import android.view.MenuItem
    import android.view.View
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.LinearLayout
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.GridLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    
    @Suppress("DEPRECATION")
    class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        lateinit var activity: Activity
        val userList = ArrayList<ProductInfoGetSet>()
        private lateinit var btnProductAdd: Button
        lateinit var llEmptyView: LinearLayout
        lateinit var llMain: LinearLayout
        lateinit var recyclerView: RecyclerView
        private lateinit var llFab: LinearLayout
        private lateinit var linearLayoutManager: LinearLayoutManager
        private lateinit var gridLayoutManager: GridLayoutManager
        private lateinit var adapter: CustomAdapter
        private var isforlist = true
    
        companion object {
            var handler: Handler = Handler()
        }
    
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
            activity = this
            initView()
            onClicks()
            setUpData()
    
            handler = @SuppressLint("HandlerLeak")
            object : Handler() {
                override fun handleMessage(msg: Message) {
                    if (msg.what == 111) {
                        val temp: Temp = msg.obj as Temp
    
                        if (temp.id == "") {
                            userList.add(
                                ProductInfoGetSet(
                                    (userList.size + 1).toString(),
                                    temp.image,
                                    temp.name,
                                    temp.quantity,
                                    temp.price,
                                )
                            )
                            adapter = CustomAdapter(activity, userList, isforlist)
                            recyclerView.adapter = adapter
                        } else {
                            for (i in userList.indices) {
                                if (userList[i].id == temp.id) {
                                    userList[i].id = temp.id
                                    userList[i].image = temp.image
                                    userList[i].name = temp.name
                                    userList[i].quantity = temp.quantity
                                    userList[i].price = temp.price
                                }
                            }
                            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged()
                        }
                    }
                    if (userList.size > 0) {
                        llEmptyView.visibility = View.GONE
                        llMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                    } else {
                        llEmptyView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                        llMain.visibility = View.GONE
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    
        private fun changeLayoutManager() {
            if (recyclerView.layoutManager == linearLayoutManager) {
                recyclerView.layoutManager = gridLayoutManager
            } else {
                recyclerView.layoutManager = linearLayoutManager
            }
        }
    
        private fun initView() {
            btnProductAdd = findViewById(R.id.btn_product_add)
            llFab = findViewById(R.id.ll_fab)
            llEmptyView = findViewById(R.id.llEmptyView)
            llMain = findViewById(R.id.llMain)
            recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.recycler_view)
            recyclerView.layoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this)
            linearLayoutManager = LinearLayoutManager(this, LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false)
            gridLayoutManager = GridLayoutManager(this, 2)
        }
    
        private fun onClicks() {
            btnProductAdd.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AddDetails::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("isFor", "Add")
                startActivity(intent)
            }
            llFab.setOnClickListener {
                val intent = Intent(this@MainActivity, AddDetails::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("isFor", "Add")
                startActivity(intent)
            }
        }
    
        private fun setUpData() {
            if (userList.size > 0) {
                llEmptyView.visibility = View.GONE
                llMain.visibility = View.VISIBLE
            } else {
                llEmptyView.visibility = View.VISIBLE
                llMain.visibility = View.GONE
            }
        }
    
        override fun onCreateOptionsMenu(menu: Menu): Boolean {
            menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu)
            return true
        }
    
        override fun onOptionsItemSelected(item: MenuItem): Boolean {
            if (item.itemId == R.id.menu_view) {
                if (userList.size > 0) {
                    changeLayoutManager()
                }
                return true
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item)
        }
    }
```

**CustomAdapter:**

```java
    package com.example.itemgetset
    
    import android.app.Activity
    import android.app.AlertDialog
    import android.content.ContentValues.TAG
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.os.Build
    import android.util.Log
    import android.view.LayoutInflater
    import android.view.View
    import android.view.ViewGroup
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.LinearLayout
    import android.widget.PopupMenu
    import android.widget.TextView
    import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
    import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    import com.google.android.material.snackbar.Snackbar
    
    @Suppress("UNREACHABLE_CODE")
    class CustomAdapter(
        private var activity: Activity,
        private val userList: ArrayList<ProductInfoGetSet>,
        private var isforlist: Boolean,
    ) :
        RecyclerView.Adapter<CustomAdapter.ViewHolder>() {
    
        override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): ViewHolder {
            val itemview =
                LayoutInflater.from(parent.context).inflate(R.layout.list_layout, parent, false)
            return ViewHolder(itemview)
        }
    
        @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.N)
        override fun onBindViewHolder(holder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    
            val productInfoGetSet: ProductInfoGetSet = userList[position]
    
            holder.txtId.text = productInfoGetSet.id
            holder.txtName.text = productInfoGetSet.name
            holder.txtQuantity.text = productInfoGetSet.quantity
            holder.txtPrice.text = productInfoGetSet.price
    
            val id = userList[position].id
            Log.e(TAG,"List item ID: $id")
    
    
            holder.buttonViewOption.setOnClickListener {
    
                val popup = PopupMenu(activity, holder.buttonViewOption)
                popup.inflate(R.menu.pop_menu)
                popup.setOnMenuItemClickListener { item ->
                    when (item.itemId) {
                        R.id.edit -> {
                            val intent = Intent(activity, AddDetails::class.java)
                            intent.putExtra("isFor", "Update")
                            intent.putExtra("id", productInfoGetSet.id)
                            intent.putExtra("image", productInfoGetSet.image)
                            intent.putExtra("name", productInfoGetSet.name)
                            intent.putExtra("quantity", productInfoGetSet.quantity)
                            intent.putExtra("price", productInfoGetSet.price)
                            activity.startActivity(intent)
                        }
                        R.id.delete -> {
                            val builder = AlertDialog.Builder(activity)
                            builder.setTitle("Delete")
                            builder.setMessage("Do you want to delete the item?")
    
                            builder.setPositiveButton("Yes") { _, _ ->
                                userList.removeAt(position)
                                notifyItemRemoved(position)
                                val snack = Snackbar
                                    .make(
                                        holder.linearly,
                                        "Item was removed from the list.",
                                        Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT
                                    )
                                snack.show()
                            }
                            builder.setNegativeButton("No") { _, _ ->
                            }
                            val dialog: AlertDialog = builder.create()
                            dialog.show()
                        }
                    }
                    false
                }
                popup.show()
            }
        }
    
        override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long {
            return position.toLong()
        }
    
        override fun getItemCount(): Int {
            return userList.size
        }
    
        class ViewHolder(itemView: View) : RecyclerView.ViewHolder(itemView) {
            val txtName = itemView.findViewById<TextView>(R.id.txt_name)
            val txtId = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_id) as TextView
            var imgList = itemView.findViewById(R.id.img_list) as ImageView
            val txtQuantity = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_quantity) as TextView
            val txtPrice = itemView.findViewById(R.id.txt_price) as TextView
            val linearly: LinearLayout = itemView.findViewById(R.id.linearlayout)
            val buttonViewOption = itemView.findViewById<View>(R.id.txt_Options) as TextView
        }
    }
```

**AddDetails:**

```java
    package com.example.itemgetset
    
    import android.annotation.SuppressLint
    import android.app.Activity
    import android.content.Intent
    import android.content.pm.PackageManager
    import android.database.Cursor
    import android.graphics.Bitmap
    import android.graphics.BitmapFactory
    import android.net.Uri
    import android.os.Build
    import android.os.Bundle
    import android.os.Message
    import android.provider.MediaStore
    import android.widget.Button
    import android.widget.EditText
    import android.widget.ImageView
    import android.widget.Toast
    import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
    
    class AddDetails : AppCompatActivity() {
    
        private lateinit var btnSubmit: Button
        private lateinit var edtName: EditText
        private lateinit var edtQuantity: EditText
        private lateinit var edtPrice: EditText
        private lateinit var imageview: ImageView
    
    
        companion object {
            private const val IMAGE_PICK_CODE = 1000
            private const val PERMISSION_CODE = 1001
        }
    
        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n", "ResourceType")
        override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.add_item)
            supportActionBar?.hide()
            findViewById()
            onclick()
    
            if (intent.getStringExtra("isFor").equals("Update")) {
                intent.getStringExtra("image")?.toInt()?.let { imageview.setImageResource(it) }
                edtName.setText(intent.getStringExtra("name"))
                edtQuantity.setText(intent.getStringExtra("quantity"))
                edtPrice.setText(intent.getStringExtra("price"))
            }
        }
    
        private fun findViewById() {
            btnSubmit = findViewById(R.id.btn_submit)
            edtName = findViewById(R.id.edt_name)
            edtQuantity = findViewById(R.id.edt_quantity)
            edtPrice = findViewById(R.id.edt_price)
            imageview = findViewById(R.id.img_add)
        }
    
        @SuppressLint("ResourceType")
        private fun onclick() {
    
            btnSubmit.setOnClickListener {
                when {
                    edtName.text.trim().isEmpty() -> {
                        edtName.error = "Please Enter Product Name"
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            "Please Enter Product Name",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                    }
                    edtQuantity.text.trim().isEmpty() -> {
                        edtQuantity.error = "Please Enter Product Quantity"
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            "Please Enter Product Quantity",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
                    }
                    edtPrice.text.trim().isEmpty() -> {
                        edtPrice.error = "Please Enter Product Price"
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            "Please Enter Product Price",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        )
                            .show()
                    }
                    else -> {
                        Toast.makeText(
                            applicationContext,
                            "Product Added Successfully ",
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                        ).show()
    
                        val temp = Temp()
                        temp.image = imageview.()
                        temp.name = edtName.text.toString()
                        temp.quantity = edtQuantity.text.toString()
                        temp.price = edtPrice.text.toString()
    
                        if (intent.getStringExtra("isFor").equals("Update")) {
                            temp.id = intent.getStringExtra("id").toString()
                        }
    
                        val message: Message = Message.obtain()
                        message.what = 111
                        message.obj = temp
                        MainActivity.handler.sendMessage(message)
                        finish()
                    }
                }
            }
            imageview.setOnClickListener {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                    if (checkSelfPermission(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED
                    ) {
                        val permissions = arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
                        requestPermissions(permissions, PERMISSION_CODE)
                    } else {
                        pickImageFromGallery()
                    }
                } else {
                    pickImageFromGallery()
                }
            }
        }
    
        override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
            requestCode: Int,
            permissions: Array<out String>,
            grantResults: IntArray,
        ) {
            when (requestCode) {
                PERMISSION_CODE -> {
                    if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] ==
                        PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                    ) {
                        pickImageFromGallery()
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(this, "Permission denied", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    }
                }
            }
            super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        }
    
        private fun pickImageFromGallery() {
            val intent = Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK)
            intent.type = "image/*"
            startActivityForResult(intent, IMAGE_PICK_CODE)
        }
    
        override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    
            if (requestCode == IMAGE_PICK_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null) {
    
                val pickedImage: Uri? = data.data
    
                val filePath = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                val cursor: Cursor? =
                    pickedImage?.let { contentResolver.query(it, filePath, null, null, null) }
                cursor?.moveToFirst()
                val imagePath: String = cursor?.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(filePath[0]))!!
                val options = BitmapFactory.Options()
                options.inPreferredConfig = Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
                val bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options)
    
                // Do something with the bitmap
                intent = Intent(applicationContext,CustomAdapter::class.java)
                intent.putExtra("image",bitmap)
                startActivity(intent)
    
                // At the end remember to close the cursor or you will end with the RuntimeException!
                cursor.close()
            }
        }
    }
```

**Temp.Kt:**

```java
package com.example.itemgetset

    class Temp {
        var id: String = ""
        var image = ""
        var name: String = ""
        var quantity: String = ""
        var price: String = ""
    }

ProductInfoGetSet: -

    package com.example.itemgetset
    
    import android.widget.ImageView
    
    class ProductInfoGetSet(
        var id: String,
        var image: String,
        var name: String,
        var quantity: String,
        var price: String
    )
```

**Logcat:**

```
2020-09-10 17:33:00.170 9328-9328/? E/mple.itemgetse: Unknown bits set in runtime_flags: 0x28000
2020-09-10 17:33:11.669 9328-9328/com.example.itemgetset E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/Pictures/Instagram/IMG_20200830_174335_408.jpg: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
2020-09-10 17:33:11.672 9328-9328/com.example.itemgetset E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.example.itemgetset, PID: 9328
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1000, result=-1, data=Intent { dat=content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content://media/external/images/media/498/ORIGINAL/NONE/image/jpeg/1143469803 flg=0x1 clip={text/uri-list U:content://com.google.android.apps.photos.contentprovider/-1/1/content%3A%2F%2Fmedia%2Fexternal%2Fimages%2Fmedia%2F498/ORIGINAL/NONE/image%2Fjpeg/1143469803} }} to activity {com.example.itemgetset/com.example.itemgetset.AddDetails}: java.lang.NullPointerException: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options) must not be null
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4973)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:5014)
        at android.app.servertransaction.ActivityResultItem.execute(ActivityResultItem.java:51)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:135)
        at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:95)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2131)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:107)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7707)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:516)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:950)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options) must not be null
        at com.example.itemgetset.AddDetails.onActivityResult(AddDetails.kt:173)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:8145)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:4966)
```

How to define imageview in temp file?

Comment: `NullPointerException` BitmapFactory.decodeFile(imagePath, options) must not be null

Comment: if ( imagePath==null) { Toast(  ... sorry .. imagepath is null  ); return;}

Comment: On Android 10 and 11 you cannot use the .DATA column.

Comment: Thank you for that but it was done by bitmap

Comment: Sorry, what are you trying to say? Can you react to the point please on my remarks as in this way this will not come further.